# Google Directions API - rendering route without some legs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, routes

I have Google Direction API showing my route defined by:

```
(base) -> origin -> waypoints[] -> destination -> (base):
```

The code looks like this.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

var origin = document.getElementById('origin');
var waypoints = [];
var waypointElements = document.getElementsByName('waypoints[]');
for(var i=0; i<waypointElements.length; i++)
{
  waypoints.push({location:waypointElements[i].value,stopover:true});
}
var destination = document.getElementById('destination');

directionsService.route({origin:origin.value,
                         waypoints:waypoints,
                         destination:destination.value,
                         travelMode:'DRIVING'},
      function(response,status)
      {
        if(status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      }
```

How to display route without first or last legs (from base to origin, and from destination to base). My route calculates the whole BUS trip, from base to origin point, then through waypoints to destination and finally back to base. I'd like to have route calculation for all these points but want to show only route from origin over waypoints to destination (without base extra distances).

I could make one route without starting and ending base and another one with them but I do not want to fetch Google Directions data twice if I do not have to!

So the question actually is, how to request full route (with starting and ending bases) from Google, remove starting and ending bases from response object, and give this "trimmed" route response to directionsDisplay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove legs from the [response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsResult) returned from the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions).

```
if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  // remove the first and last legs from the response legs array
  response.routes[0].legs = response.routes[0].legs.slice(1,response.routes[0].legs.length-1);
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
} else console.log("Directions request failed, status=" + status)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z9h4df3L/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });
  var origin = document.getElementById('origin');
  var waypoints = [];
  var waypointElements = document.getElementsByName('waypoints[]');
  console.log("origin=" + origin.value);
  for (var i = 0; i < waypointElements.length; i++) {
    console.log("waypoint[" + i + "]=" + waypointElements[i].value);
    waypoints.push({
      location: waypointElements[i].value,
      stopover: true
    });
  }

  var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
  console.log("destination=" + destination.value);

  directionsService.route({
      origin: origin.value,
      waypoints: waypoints,
      destination: destination.value,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log(response.routes[0])
        response.routes[0].legs = response.routes[0].legs.slice(1, response.routes[0].legs.length - 1);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else console.log("Directions request failed, status=" + status)
    })

}
```

```css
#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

#right-panel {
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
  <div>
    <b>Start:</b>
    <input id="origin" value="Newark, NJ" />
    <br>
    <b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
    <input value="Weehawken, NJ 07086, USA" name="waypoints[]" />
    <input value="Hoboken, NJ, USA" name="waypoints[]" />
    <input value="City Hall Park, New York, NY 10007, USA" name="waypoints[]" />
    <br>
    <b>End:</b>
    <input id="destination" value="Newark, NJ">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```